# Write a log in .NET - permissions issue

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, security, permissions

I need in a .NET Windows Application to write some log text and then display that text to the user.

I have no specific requirements on WHERE to create the log file.

Initially I wrote the log file in the same folder with the application, but on some computers the application users had no rights to create the files...

Is there a mechanism to create however a log (text) file somewhere with minimum user rights?

Comment: My first idea would be to write the log-file in the user-directory or temp-directory. There you should have the required permission.

Comment: The user context temp location? Pretty sure that's somewhere in the My namespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it into the current users [application data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) directory. The user should have full permission there. You can request the path (in .NET) using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

This will return

> C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\

Comment: what about the TEMP directory?